# how to share static content between many war projects (using artifactory?)

Tags: gradle, artifactory, war

**current state**:

I have a dozen war projects (Gradle). All they contain/share a bundle of static data content.

Now I am pulling the bundle (from git) into each project directory, it's a kind of pasting the static content into 'src/rootContent', treating the bundle as sources.

**expected solution**:

I would like to:

1. pack the static content
2. publish the package in Artifactory
3. use the package from repo the in Gradle war projects, in a similar way like lib/jar dependencies are declared

Specially for the point 3 - what should I do in the war{} closure?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround, but I hope there are 'nicer' solutions

```
configurations {
    myStaticContentBundle
}
  dependencies {
    myStaticContentBundle "com.myCompany:myBundle:1.0"
}
task copyStaticContent(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.myStaticContentBundle
    into "src/rootContent"
}
```